# Where is the logical flaw in this PHP login code?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

There is definitely a logical flaw somewhere in this code, but I can't find it. The issue is that regardless of input, it `echo`'s success (simulating a redirect to the main page). I don't know why. Here's the code:

```
$signIn = new UserService($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbhost, $dbname); //Create new class instance 
$signIn->sec_session_start(); //Begin session
$_SESSION['token'] = $token; //Store token valualbe in super global variable

//***************************************************************************************//

//***************************************************************************************//
//Begin Login Functions

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'],$_POST['siteToken'])) {

    //Assign POST submissions to passable php variables
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passedToken = $_POST['siteToken'];

    //Check Token Values (prevent CSRF attacks)
    /*
    if($passedToken != $_SESSION['token']) {
        $error = "CSRF attack detected. Please close your browser and try again."; 
        $signIn->csrfAttackLog($username);
        echo $error;
        exit();     
    }
    */

    //Test if both fields are not null
    if($username == "" || $password = "")
    {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }

    //Start login process
    else
    {
        $success = $signIn->login($username, $password);
        if ($success == true)
        { //Login Successful
            echo "Success!"; //Direct to main page.
            exit();
        }
        //Specific login failure determination
        else 
        {
            switch ($success){
                case 1:
                    $error = "Your account has been locked.";
                    echo $error;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    $error = "Invalid Username/Password (2)";
                    echo $error;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $error = "Invalid Username/Password";
                    echo $error;
                    break;  
                case 4: 
                    $error = "Invalid Username/Password (3)";
                    echo $error;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Here's the  `login` class method:

```
    public function login($username, $password)
        {
            //****************//
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password; 
            $user_Id = "";
            $user = "";
            $hashPassword = "";
            $dbPassword = "";
            $salt = "";
            $userBrowser = "";
            //**************// Local declerations

            $this->connect(); //connect to database

            if ($stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT UserId, Username, Pass, Salt FROM user WHERE Username = :param1 LIMIT 1")) //Prepared procedure
            {
                $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->username); //Bind $this->username to parameter
                $stmt->execute(); //Execute the prepared query

                if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) //If the user exists
                {
                    $this->user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Grab the variables from the selected database row

                    $user_Id = $this->user['UserId']; //Transfer variables from array to local variables
                    $user = $this->user['Username'];
                    $dbPassword = $this->user['Pass'];
                    $salt = $this->user['Salt'];

                    if($user_Id = "")
                        echo "Why"; 
                    //Check if account has been locked
                    if($this->checkBrute($user_Id, $this->dbh) == true) 
                    {
                        //Account is locked
                        return 1; //Used in userControl as a switch condition: Indicates a locked account
                        //Possibly send an email here
                    } else {
                                $hashPassword = hash('sha512', $this->password.$salt); //Hash the password with the unique salt

                                if($dbPassword == $hashPassword) 
                                { //Check if the password in the database matches the password the user submitted
                                //Password is correct!

                                $userBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Get the user-agent string of the user
                                $_SESSION['p_id'] = $user_Id; //Store user id to global session variable
                                $_SESSION['userName'] = $user; //Store username to global session variable
                                $_SESSION['loginString'] = hash('sha512', $hashPassword.$userBrowser); //Hash the concentanation of the hashedpassword (password + salt) and userBrowser
                                //Login succesful!!!!!!
                                return true;
                                } else {
                                        //Password is not correct
                                        //Record this attempt in the database
                                        $now = time();
                                        $userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                                        $insert = $this->dbh->query("INSERT INTO loginattempts (UserId, UserIp, EventTime) VALUES ('$user_Id', 'userIP', '$now')");
                                        if($insert == false){
                                            return 2; //Used in userControl as a switch condition: Indicated a failure to log failed login attempt
                                        } else {
                                            return 3; //Used in userControl as a switch condition: Indicates an inccorect password
                                        }
                                    }
                            }

                }
                else 
                {
                    //No user exists
                    return 4;
                }
            }
        }
```

I know the SQL queries work: I've tested them outside this code. I don't understand why it keeps returning true. PHP hasn't thrown any exceptions or errors (and yes, I've read many times "don't write your own login functions. Use one that already works." This is not a public site. I'm just doing it for the heck of it). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know you say it echoes `success` regardless of input, but does it echo success when there is no input given?

Comment: `if ($success == true)` - this will do loose type matching, and I suspect is casting your return values to boolean, so any non-0 return will match. Try `if ($success === true)` for a type comparison as well.

Comment: @Kyle I haven't tried that in particular. I have three validation levels that prevent a null login. I'll try removing them and give it a shot.

Comment: @andrewsi That could be the case. Why would my return values be cast into boolean, and is there a way to force my function to return numerical or string values?

Comment: This probably has nothing to due with the issue, but `if($user_Id = "")` should probably be `if($user_Id == "")`

Comment: Not exactly the bug you are looking for, but `if($username == "" || $password = "")` should become `if($username == "" || $password == "")` ( = to == ), you are blanking the password instead of checking for an empty string.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net Ha, nice catch. You've saved me some time.

Comment: @Sean I left that segment by mistake. It was just for testing.

Comment: @andrewsi Can you put your comment into an answer? That did the trick. I would like to choose it as the answer.

Comment: @Mlagma - PHP is only loosely typed, so it treats 1 as a string, a boolean, an int, or a float, depending on how you use it. If you want to do a type comparison as well as a value one, then `$x === "1"` will be true if $x is 1, and if $x is also an string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login code has various return codes - `true` if everything works, or numbers to indicate various error states. You're then checking the return value with:

```
if ($success == true)
```

PHP isn't strongly typed, so it will cast return values to a boolean for that comparison; and any non-0 integer will evaluate to true. To do a type check, as well as a value check, you need to use the strict comparison operator:

```
if ($success === true)
```

That will evaluate true if `$success` is both true and a boolean.